# How to add items to array from a setter

Tags: php, arrays, class, for-loop, setter

I am a newbie to PHP OOP, I want to know how to add or push a new item to an array from a setter and display all items, here is my code.

```
$r = "/some regex here/";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($p[0]); $i++)
{
   preg_match($r, $text, $value);
   preg_match($r, $schema, $name);

   $this->setTheOutput('name', $name[1]);
   $this->setTheOutput('value', $value[1]);
}
```

And this is the array in another class

```
protected $output = [];

protected function setTheOutput($name, string $value)
{
   $this->output[$name] = $value;
}
```

The result should look like

> { {{"name":"{{Name}}","value":"Foo"}, {"name":"{{Age}}","value":"20"},
>   {"name":"{{mission}}","value":"none"}}, {
>   {{"name":"{{Name}}","value":"Bar"}, {"name":"{{Age}}","value":"25"},
>   {"name":"{{mission}}","value":"none"}} }

Whenever I loop over For loop, I always get the last item, I want to get all items and display them like mentioned in the result.

Comment: setter overwrites existing data, so you have to gather your data and set it after the loop

Comment: Yes, but how can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are continuously overwriting the values of the same keys.

You may want to add values to the last associative arrays if the corresponding key does not exists, and allocating a new associative array in case of saturation.

```
protected $output = [];

protected function setTheOutput($name, string $value)
{
   $last = end($this->output);
   if(array_key_exists($name, $last) {
       $this->output[] = [$name => $value];
   } else {
       $last[$name] = $value;
   }
}
```

The structure will be something like this:

```
Array(
    Array(
        key1 => value1,
        key2 => value2
    ),
    Array(
        key1 => value3,
        key2 => value4
    ),
    ...
    Array(
        key1 => value5,
        key2 => value6
    )
)
```

The function get the last element of the outer array, and checks if the key that has to be inserted already exists in the last inner array or not.
If it exists, then another inner array will be allocated and the key-value couple is assigned here.
Otherwise, the key-value couple will be simply appended.

Display values:

```
foreach($output as $line) {
    foreach($line as $k => $v) {
        echo "key ${k} value ${v}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I think this will solve it just in case I have different keys, but I want to add new items to  $output  with same keys, I have updated my question, please can you have look. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried my solution? It should be exactly what you want

Comment: Check my explaination for further details. Hope that will work

Comment: thank you, but before I use your solution , I var_dump($output) and found out that it contains all keys and values, so I just need to display them, but do not know how.